# Why are Proto-West Germanic hwaʀ and OHG wēr cognate?

Tags: proto-germanic

Why are Proto-West Germanic hwaʀ and OHG wēr cognate?
What is the kind of mutation a > ē?

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? Are you asking for the proto-form and derivation; or for the evidence that they are; or something else, and what?

Comment: @user6726 I am asking for the evidence that Proto-West Germanic a and OHG ē may be cognate without i-mutation.

Answer (score 1):

*a > *e before *z in NWGmc (see Ringe). Another example is *razdō > WGmc *rerdu > OE reord (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reord).